# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the

Tags: php, javascript, json, socket

Tengo problemas al intentar parsear mi JS

Aqui trato de parsearlo

```
var JSONdata    = JSON.parse(message); //parseo la informacion
// console.log(JSONdata);
  nombre = JSONdata[0].nombre;
  nit = JSONdata[0].nit;
  funcionario = JSONdata[0].funcionario;
  nro_radicado = JSONdata[0].nro_radicado;
  nrosolicitud = JSONdata[0].nrosolicitud;
  consulta = JSONdata[0].consulta;
  hora = JSONdata[0].hora;
```

Mi archivo que usa ajax para conectar... con la funcion `send(data)` envio la info a la mi archivo js

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "quotes_controller.php",
        data: "fecha_cita="+fecha_cita+"&atendio="+atendio+"&nombre="+nombre+"&apellido="+apellido+"&LISTA="+LISTA+"&nroradicado="+nroradicado+"&nrosolicitud="+nrosolicitud,
        dataType:"html",
        success: function(data) 
        {///// here sen data response
          send(data);// array JSON
/////////////////////////////////////
          window.location.href = 'index.php'
        },
        error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
            alert('algo fallo...');
            console.log(jqXHR);
        }
        });
```

Mi php hace el Json despues de insertar en la BD

```
$arrayjson = array();
$arrayjson[] = array(
                    'nit'          => '1223344',//nit del solicitante
                    'nombre'       => 'el nombre',// nombres concatenados 
                    'funcionario'  => $_POST['atendio'],//quien atiende
                    'nro_radicado' => $nro_radicado,//numero de radicado
                    'nrosolicitud' => $_POST['nrosolicitud'],// numero de solicitud
                    'consulta'     => 'APORTAR PLANOS',//tipo de consulta que se realiza
                    'hora'         => $hora//hora de agendamiento
);

echo json_encode($arrayjson);
```

El `concole.log(message);` de la infor que llega antes de parsearla Es...

```
[{"nit":"1223344","nombre":"el nombre","funcionario":"10","nro_radicado":"","nrosolicitud":"","consulta":"APORTAR PLANOS","hora":"11:04:47"}]
```

Todos los datos tienen valores ... no se que pasa .. de antemano gracias...

Comment: Creo que es el dataType, ponlo en "json" a ver si eso arregla el problema, por cierto, qué dice el error en su totalidad?

Comment: Puedes especificar el error o el problema exactamente.

Answer (score 1):

lo que sucede esque estas trayendo formato hora que trae los dos puntos(:),esto provoca el error has lo siguiente:

```
var tunombrevariable= JSON.stringify(message);
var tunombrevariable=JSON.parse(tunombrevariable);
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse() = Analiza una **cadena de texto** JSON;

El message es un tipo de dato array

```
var message = [{"nit":"1223344","nombre":"el nombre","funcionario":"10","nro_radicado":"","nrosolicitud":"","consulta":"APORTAR PLANOS","hora":"11:04:47"}];
```

Primero tienes que convertirlo a tipo de dato string, para que quede de la siguiente manera

```
var messageString = '[{"nit":"1223344","nombre":"el nombre","funcionario":"10","nro_radicado":"","nrosolicitud":"","consulta":"APORTAR PLANOS","hora":"11:04:47"}]';
```

para utilizarlo

```
var parse = JSON.parse(messageString);
```